# Como ao clicar em link abrir painel correspondente

Tags: jquery, css

Ao clicar em um link no rodapé de minha página estou tentando abrir o painel correspondente que aponta para uma página específica, mas não estou conseguindo, vi um exemplo aqui mas não consegui adaptar.

A imagem a seguir ilustra a minha questão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código da página que contém os painéis está assim:

```
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Disponibilidade de Entrega:<br><br>                             
                            As peças adquiridas estarão disponíveis para entrega de acordo com as quantidades mencionadas em estoque. Com entrega prevista entre 1-8 dias úteis (SEDEX) ou 4-24 dias úteis (PAC), após confirmação do pagamento. O prazo de entrega depende do seu CEP e é calculado automaticamente no seu carrinho de compras.<br><br>

                            Segurança ao comprar pela internet:<br><br>
                            Os pagamentos são feitos através do sistema PAGSEGURO da UOL. Suas informações ficam protegidas e seguras. Os pagamentos no cartão passam por uma análise anti-fraude para proteger a loja e o cliente.<br><br>

                            Diferenças nas características do produto:<br><br>
                            As fotos do site são ilustrativas, podendo haver variação em relação à cor original.<br><br>

                            Fique por dentro das novidades:<br><br>
                            Você fica por dentro das novidades RendaMais Lingerie curtindo a nossa página no Facebook, e seguindo nosso Instagram! Faça também o seu cadastro no site para receber promoções e novidades.<br><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!---->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading3">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">
                                <span class="dot"></span> Política de Pagamento
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading3">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Formas de pagamento aceitas:<br>
                            1. Pagseguro: Cartão de Crédito: VISA, Mastercard, Elo, American Express, Hipercard, Hiper, Rede Shop (até 3x sem juros) <br>
                            2. Transferência Bancária (DOC OU TED): Sicredi Agroempresarial PR/SP (à vista)<br>
                            3. Depósito em Conta: Sicredi Agroempresarial PR/SP (à vista).<br><br>

                            Prazo para Confirmação do Pagamento:<br>
                            1.Pagamentos no cartão de crédito são confirmados geralmente em 1 dia útil.<br>
                            2. Transferências bancárias e Depósitos são confirmadas geralmente em 1 dia útil.<br>
                            Dicas para garantir a agilidade na entrega do seu pedido.<br>
                            1. Pagamentos com cartão de crédito: na tela de pagamento informe corretamente todos os dados do titular do cartão de crédito. Caso algum dado esteja incorreto o pagamento poderá passar por uma análise de até 48h, o que poderá aumentar o prazo de entrega do seu pedido.<br>
                            2. Pagamento por depósito em conta ou Transferência bancária (DOC OU TED): após efetuar o depósito nos informe por WhatsApp (44) 9.9919-8860 ou pelo e-mail contato@rendamaislingerie.com.br o número do seu pedido, o valor depositado e a data e horário do depósito.<br>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

No rodapé tentei fazer isso:

```
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="widget widget-categories">
                        <h4 class="widget-title">INFORMAÇÕES</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="empresa.php">Sobre Nós</a></li>
                            <li><a href="faq.php#collapse2">Como Comprar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="faq.php#collapse3">Política de Pagamento</a></li>
                            <li><a href="faq.php#collapse4">Política de Entrega</a></li>
                            <li><a href="faq.php#collapse5">Trocas e Devoluções</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

O script está assim:

```
        $(function(){

    // check if there is a hash in the url
    if ( window.location.hash != '' )
    {
        // remove any accordion panels that are showing (they have a class of 'in')
        $('.collapse').removeClass('in');

        // show the panel based on the hash now:
        $(window.location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');
    }

    });
```

Mas quando estou na `faq.php` não funciona, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Não entendi. Você quer abrir uma outra página?

Comment: Isso @JorgeMatheus, ao cicar no rodapé abrir o item correspondente na página faq.php

Comment: Coloque um `id` nos paineis: `<div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading3">` no rodapé:  `<li><a data-tab="collapse3" href="http://url.com.br/faq.php#collapse3">Política de Pagamento</a></li>`   o `#` serve como uma âncora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para deixar o `collapse` do `bootstrap` acionado, a classe `in` deve estar envolvida na `div` do elemento.

Você pode fazer simplesmente assim:

```
      $(function(){

    // check if there is a hash in the url
    if ( window.location.hash != '' )
    {
        // remove any accordion panels that are showing (they have a class of 'in')
        $('.collapse').removeClass('in');

        // show the panel based on the hash now:
        $(window.location.hash).addClass('in'); /*irá adicionar a classe 
no elemento com o id correspondente*/
    }

    });
```